# Can I legally decompile my own binary code created by copyrighted compiler?

Tags: copyright, licensing, eula

I've the following scenario:

I've written some programming code which I own, but I lost the source code, however I've binary which was created by the compiler.

Can I simply decode my own binary code back to the source code if I know how to do it?

---

Here are the technical details to reproduce that scenario on the computer:

1. Write a dummy program:

   ```
   $ echo "void start() { }" > foo.mq4
   ```
2. I've downloaded the compiler (without accepting any agreement):

   ```
   $ curl -O https://download.mql5.com/cdn/web/metaquotes.software.corp/mt5/mql.exe
   ```
3. Compile the program (which generated encrypted `foo.ex4` binary file):

   ```
   $ mql.exe /mql4 foo.mq4
   MQL4/MQL5 Compiler build 1162 (02 Jul 2015)
   Copyright 2001-2015, MetaQuotes Software Corp.
   foo.mq4 : information: Compiling 'foo.mq4'
   Result: 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
   ```
4. I lost my source code:

   ```
   $ rm -v foo.mq4
   removed ‘foo.mq4’
   ```
5. I'm trying to decompile the binary file using a tool to recover my source code:

   ```
   $ ./decompiler foo.ex4
   ```

Is that perfectly fine to do that, or not? Or it depends, if so, on what?

Comment: One thing it very certainly depends on is which jurisdiction applies.

Comment: In your very simple example there are no libraries linked in. There may be (probably is) terms in the compiler EULA that prohibit reverse engineering libraries supplied with the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I certainly don't see why this would not be legal. If you wrote a novel in English and paid someone to translate it into Spanish you could translate it back if you want.

The copyright scenario is they have copyright in the compiler; you own the copyright in the input and output of it. The compiler's creators have no claim on the output because there is none of their creativity in it.

Comment: Unless you use publishing company which prevents your from doing so in their Publishing Agreement.

Comment: @kenorb not relevant, assume a self or unpublished work

Comment: In here I believe by compiling the program, I automatically accept the agreement. So potentially I could not have rights to decompile the binary, as I didn't create that kind of output on my own, but by using copyrighted program.

Comment: What law in particular are you worried about?

Comment: Not any particular. Just if this is a legal scenario to do, unless it depends on the agreement which I didn't read/found associated with the compiler, so I've to dig it out from somewhere and read it. However there is no any info about any license in place when running the compiler. So I could only assume that you're right.

Comment: I think your last statement merits further support: Can a copyrighted compiler assert copyright over its output?  I *think* the answer is *no* because the output is always a "derivative work."  But [perhaps the best answer on that sort of question](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/1152/10) was provided by you so can you confirm/clarify?

Comment: @kenorb How do you figure that by compiling the program you automatically accept the agreement? Are you imagining some jurisdiction (other than the United States) where ordinary use is covered by copyright law?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't know, I believe it's the same way as you going to some website and in their policy you can find something like: 'by using this service you're agree to our terms ...'.

Comment: @kenorb I don't see how that could apply to using a work you already lawfully possess and that you obtained possession of without agreeing to anything. That would be like buying a book, reading it, and then finding that the back page said, "by reading this book ...". By distributing the work without any EULA, I would think they authorized the ordinary use of the work by lawful recipients.

Comment: Actually I think your analogy is wrong.  The translator will have copyright in the translation (so *two* copyrights will apply to the translation - yours and the theirs).  The difference is that a compiler can't own copyright, so I think the OP will be OK.